# How to call the MongoLabs (mongoDB) RESTFULL APIS for adding documents in php?

Tags: php, jquery, mongodb, mlab

On the MongoLabs documentation to insert a document the following jQuery code is given in the example:
http://docs.mlab.com/data-api/

```
    $.ajax( { url: "https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/my-db/collections/my-coll?apiKey=myAPIKey",
      data: JSON.stringify( { "x" : 1 } ),
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json" } );
```

I have to call the RESTFULL API end point via PHP for my android app..

How do i make a POST request in php to call the MongoLABs data APIS?

How to convert the above jquery code to php code?

I have tried the following code but no luck. Can someone tell the mistake in the following code or tell how to do it using php?

```
   <?php
   $x=array(
    'x' => 2
);
   $data=json_encode($x);
   echo $data;
   $postdata = $data;


    $opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'content' => $postdata
        )
    );

    $context  = stream_context_create($opts);

    $result = file_get_contents('http://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/mydb/collections/mycoll?apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', false, $context);

    echo $result;
    ?>
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're using mLab's REST API instead of the native MongoDB PHP driver? https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/php/ & http://blog.mlab.com/2014/05/mongodb-driver-tips-tricks-php/

Comment: Yes .. We are using a free hosting server.. And the shell access is not provided in the free hosting.. SO how do I use the DATA API instead in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Got the mistake:
If anyone has the same issue or want to use the mLabs data api.. Use the following:

```
    $x=array(
        'x' => '2'
    );
    $data=json_encode($x);
    //echo $data;

    $opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'header'  => 'Content-type: application/json',
            'content' => $data
        )
    );

    $context  = stream_context_create($opts);

    $result = file_get_contents('https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/mydb/collections/mycoll?apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxx', false, $context);

    echo $result;
```

But try to avoid using the DATA apis as the key is vulnerable and anyone with the key will have access to your entire DB..